# Missing MOSS 2007 Functionality?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, sharepoint, moss

I've installed MOSS 2007 a number of times, but I always run into the same problem.  The installation goes just fine, but MOSS seems to be missing functionality.

In the Administration page, clicking the 'OK' button in Create or Extend a Web Application does absolutely nothing.  Also, clicking certain links evoke no response either.  I think something is wrong with my setup.  All of the links that do not work display javascript in the bottom-left of the browser.  I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it.

I'm running MOSS 2007 on Windows Server 2003.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding the SharePoint Central Administration site to your Trusted Sites in IE?

Comment: Wow. I can't believe I missed something so simple!  I also can't believe that there were no signs pointing to such a simple solutions. :S  Thanks a million!